# Killing the application manually when catching a exception?

Tags: php, oop, exception

I have a connection class which initializes the database credentials when I `__construct` it.

Whenever this fails, it throws an exception that the credentials cant be set because the file is empty or the variables aren't set.

The variables aren't set now.

But I can still call the object for calling other functions inside that class, which I don't want because this is not possible with no variables. Like this:

```
$connection = new Connection(); //Causes exception because variables aren't set
$connection->initialize(); //Should not be ran, because the variables aren't set. Application shouldn't continue as well.
$connection->doFurtherThings(); //Which shouldn't be run as well, because the application couldn't go further without a db connection
```

What is the reason for this while i caught the exception and didn't let the values initialize?

```
public function __construct() {
    try {
        require "Configuration.php";
        $credentials = new Configuration('config.ini'); //Doesn't matter. just sets the configuration file
        $credential  = $credentials->getItems(); //Gets the items

        if (isset($credential['engine'], $credential['host'], $credential['dbname'], $credential['username'], $credential['password'])) {
            $this->engine   = $credential['engine'];
            $this->host     = filter_var($credential['host'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
            $this->dbname   = $credential['dbname'];
            $this->username = $credential['username'];
            $this->password = $credential['password'];
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Login credentials aren't not set");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Do I have to `die()` the application myself, inside of the `catch(Exception)`? I thought that the exception did that.

Comment: So you don't want ->getItems to be called, is that correct?

Comment: @Coulton No, i dont want that the application could go further at all. When it isnt possible to initialize the database variables. Wich includes that i cant call `$connection->initialize()`

Comment: It's implementor decision how to deal with exceptions, so don't catch the exception in constructor.

Comment: @AlexandruG. I dont get you mean, when the DB should be initialized for the user, and it doesnt work. The application shouldnt go further.

Comment: ok, so add `exit();` to your exception

Comment: @Coulton Yes, i think that would be the best solution.

Comment: @Coulton But that's what exceptions do right? exit or die your application when this part of the code doesnt work.

Comment: No, calling an exception makes it JUMP to the `catch` and then you can do what you want from within there.  In your case you want to finish the page loading

Comment: @Coulton Oh, so this would still be the best solution? (can you edit that in your answer, so i can accept it)

Comment: @Bas If you want to do it properly, give my answer a read. It'll help you in the future.

Comment: @Jimbo I'll sure do, but is it okay i'll do it tommorow? Im kind of busy at the moment, sorry

Comment: @Bas Of course, it's for your learning, do it when you like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you are doing.

You're trying to use a **Configuration Object**. That's awesome, and is exactly what you should be doing. However, how you are going about it isn't really the best way.

Before you even *get* to the code that uses the configuration object, you should be constructing your configuration object and checking that *that* object is all setup and *valid* before attempting to use the object within another one. It is not the responsibility of the consuming object to validate data from an internal one in the context of your system here.

First and foremost, your `Credentials` object. We're creating an interface here that says that "Any Credentials object must have a `validate()` method, and that method throws an exception if the credentials are invalid.

```
interface Credentials
{
   /**
    * @throws CredentialsValidationException
    */
    public function validate();
}
```

Why is there an `validate()` method? Because you **shouldn't be placing business logic in your object's constructor**. Future developers know that they can call `validate()` and *that* will let them know whether or not the object has valid credentials.

Now onto your specific configuration. In this `Configuration` object, you're stating: "To have a valid object, the user **must** provide a host, database name, engine, username and a password.

```
class Configuration implements Credentials
{
    protected $host;
    protected $engine;
    protected $dbName;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;

   /**
    * We're NOT validating here, we're just stating that this object requires
    * these parameters to become an actual object
    */
    public function __construct($host, $engine, $dbName, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->dbName   = $dbName;
        $this->engine   = $engine;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

   /**
    * As our Credentials interface requires, validate everything
    *
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function validate()
    {
        // Check this is a valid object
        // Consider using a Validation object passed in via Dependency Injection
        // If it's not a valid object, throw a CredentialsValidationException
    }
}
```

Now we've moved the responsibility of having valid credentials into the `Configuration` (`Credentials`) object itself. The next step is to actually use this object.

```
class Connection
{
    protected $credentials;

   /**
    * @param Credentials $credentials
    */
    public  function __construct(Credentials $credentials)
    {
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }
}
```

In your `Connection` object, you're stating you require any object that implements the `Credentials` interface. So not only do you gain the ability to use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) here, you're decoupling application configuration from your classes (what you were trying to do originally).

You are also now using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection); passing in objects via constructors / methods so to be used by the consuming class. This means your code is decoupled and you can use those objects anywhere else in the application, or in an entirely different library if you so wish.

Here is the object API you can now use:

```
$credentials = new Configuration('host', 'engine', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');

try
{
    $credentials->validate();

    $connection = new Connection($credentials);

    // @todo Whatever else you want to do
}
catch (CredentialsValidationException $e) 
{
    // @todo Log the error here with a logger object (check out monolog)
    // @todo Make sure the user viewing the code gets a nice response back
}
```

If you want to *force* a valid `Connection` object, simply call `Configuration::validate()` in the method you are using it in (not the constructor, though). You could use a factory to build the object, and force calling validate for you. Do what you like!

On the note of dying, don't die in an application. Do what you need to let both the developer debugging (you) and the user (you, or someone else) know about what is wrong in different ways. Usually you'll log for the developer and give a message for the user. Catch the exception and echo what the problem is.

Closing note, this is *one* way of doing this. You could use a `Validation` object. You could make `validate()` become `isValid()` instead, and just return true / false. You could make the `Connection` object call `validate()` / `isValid()` - it depends on your architecture and what you want to do. The point is you've decoupled these two classes and used best practice at the same time.

Final thought - make sure you add phpdocs like I did in my code. Future developer won't want to kill you. And I suggest checking out an IDE that throws up little notices, like [phpstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), when you do something silly in your code.

Comment: @Jimbo first of all, thank you for time :) i've been reading through your answer and it looks very good. The only point on it thats its abit above my level, i have almost no experience with OOP. So i have a few questions, what exactly does the validate method do? And is it a boolean? And where do i check for example where the database is open in this case? Do i have to declare new objects or can i do it with the existing onces? I'm sorry if my english is bad, i'm currently typing this on my phone.

Comment: The validate method is where you check that the strings aren't empty, and that they're within your given parameters etc (like the host is an ip address with `filter_var()`). You can check where the database is open in each method (`$this->checkConnected();`), for example, before doing everything else.

Comment: @Jimbo and inside that `$this->checkConnected();` is there some kind of if statement, and if that fails you throw an exception?

Comment: @Bas I guess you would have some code making sure the connection works. And if it doesn't, you would throw a `ConnectionException` perhaps.

Comment: @Jimbo Alright, one last question. I'm sorry i took so long, but what if i would make another function inside the `Connection` class, wich requires no arguments. How do i access each one of the credentials?

Comment: In your Connection constructor the credentials are set to $this->credentials. A class property. So in another function you can say $this->credentials, if you need them. Your credentials can have getters.

Comment: @Jimbo but doesnt this only give me access to the interface's methods? ( 'validate()' )

Comment: @Bas Nope, an interface only specifies what *must* exist within implementing classes. You're completely free to add your own methods to the class - the interface merely ensures that the objects all use *at least* these same method call. This way, imagine you're `foreach()`ing around an array of these objects, you know that `validate()` **definitely** exists in these.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in the comments, it should be caller decision how to deal with an exception, not the called class.

In your constructor you should throw the exception if something goes wrong and leave the calling class to decide how to deal with that exception.

```
public function __construct() {

    require "Configuration.php";
    $credentials = new Configuration('config.ini'); //Doesnt matter. just sets the configuration file
    $credential  = $credentials->getItems(); //Gets the items

    if (isset($credential['engine'], $credential['host'], $credential['dbname'], $credential['username'], $credential['password'])) {
        $this->engine   = $credential['engine'];
        $this->host     = filter_var($credential['host'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
        $this->dbname   = $credential['dbname'];
        $this->username = $credential['username'];
        $this->password = $credential['password'];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Login credential's arent not set");
    }
}
```

And now its caller decision what to do in case of an exception, like stop the execution for instance:

```
try {
    $connection = new Connection(); //Causes exception because variables arent set
    $connection->initialize(); //Should not be ran, because the variables arent set. Application shouldnt continue aswell.
    $connection->doFurtherThings();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage()); // Login credential's arent not set
}
```

To better illustrate this, I wrote you a [simple example](http://ideone.com/MHAzOu) and as a side note, you should really learn how execution flow works.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont really like this solution. The initialized values are a requirement.

Comment: @Bas What do you mean ?

Comment: that the initialized variable are pretty much a must. If they do not exist, the page shouldnt go further then that. because it cant load its data

Comment: @Bas Because `Connection` class will throw an exception right in the constructor, `$connection->initialize();` will not be executed in case of exception.

Comment: In wich case do you mean that? When you instantiate the `Connection();` object?

Comment: From my second code block, if `Connection` throws an exception, `initialize()` and `doFurtherThings()` methods will not be executed. See http://ideone.com/MHAzOu for example.